# React Native (getting value from text input)

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I'm doing a little personal project and I'm having some trouble getting the numeric value from the textinput. I'm either getting an error saying the function expected a string or undefined.

Below is the source code:

```
//Timer state
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState({
    work: 0.3,
    break: 0.2,
    longBreak: 0.5,
    active: "work",
  });

  const workTime = timer.work;
  const breakTime = timer.break;
  const longBreakTime = timer.longBreak;
```

This is where the value is supposed to be passed :

```
function handleChange(name, value) {
    console.log(value);

    switch (name) {
      case "work":
        setTimer({ ...timer, work: parseInt(value) });
        break;
      case "break":
        setTimer({ ...timer, break: parseInt(value) });
        break;
      case "longBreak":
        setTimer({ ...timer, longBreak: parseInt(value) });
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to retrieve the value from this text input:

```
 <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              onChange={(workTime) => handleChange("work", setTimer(workTime))}
              placeholder="Work"
              keyboardType="numeric"
              numeric
              value={workTime}
              name="work"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange={(workTime) => handleChange("work", workTime)}
```

you are passing a call to the hook function instead of the value you read from the input

Comment: I made some changes and i'm still not getting it to work, i got NaN and undefined onChange={() => handleChange("work", setTimer(timer.work))}                                
value={timer.work}